# how to access an already uploaded audio file from directory and create spectrogram of it in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am saving my audio file to /static/uploads/. I am required to read uploaded files which is dynamic from this folder and create spectrogram of the same.
Please suggest how this can be achieved.
I am trying below code however, it gives error.
app.py

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(THIS_DIR,'static','uploads')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_files():
    filename = None
    file = request.files['file']

    '''to delete any existing file in uploads folder'''
    if os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
        shutil.rmtree(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    time.sleep(5)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            error = 'No selected file'
            return render_template(error.html, error = error)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return render_template(index.html, filename=filename)

@app.route("/processing", methods=["POST","GET"]) 
def processing():
    ''' retrieves file, creates spectrogram'''
    filename = None
    filename = ('/static/uploads/' + filename).read()

    fig = create_spectrogram(filename)
    .................................
    .................................
```

*TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str*

My HTML file looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    {% if filename %}
        <audio controls>
          <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename) }}" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
    <form action = "/processing" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
        <input type = "submit" value="Discover!" >
                         
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: filename variable is always None. Hence you are getting error 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str'. I believe you need to set correct path of Aduio file to be read.

Comment: @aberry the filename will change with every upload hence, I cannot set a filename. How can I access dynamic files with each upload and perform processing on uploaded file?

Comment: Do share more code then. From this code snipper , it is not clear how are you getting filename. You are not assigning filename with any file name string.

Comment: @aberry I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to access the file and it worked successfully.

```
@app.route("/uploads", methods=["POST"]) 
def uploads():
    result = {}
 
    filename = os.listdir('static/images/uploads')
    filename = filename[0]
    print(filename)

    fig = create_spectrogram([os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)])
```

HTML Filecode is below:

```
<div class="form">
   <div class="card-body center" style=" color:black;" >
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type = "file" name = "file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"><br>
        <input style="margin-right: 60px; background-color:#F7DE40; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" type = "submit" class="btn btn-light float-left" value="Upload!" name="upload"><br><br>      
      {% if filename %}
          <audio controls>
            <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/uploads/' + filename) }}" type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
    <form style="margin-top: 5px;" action = "/prediction" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
        <input style="margin-right: 60px; background-color:#F7DE40; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" type = "submit" class="btn btn-light float-left" value="Discover!" name="discover"><br><br>
                         
    </form>
</div>
```